# Could not find the .cmi file

Tags: makefile

I would like to add a makefile for [this project](https://github.com/chengtie/sedlex-menhir). I tried the following makefile:

```
SHELL:= /bin/bash
OCAMLC= ocamlfind ocamlc -package ppx_deriving.std -package sedlex.ppx -package sedlex -package MenhirLib
OCAMLYACC=      $(OCAMLPREFIX)menhir -v
OCAMLLEX=       $(OCAMLPREFIX)ocamllex -ml

%.ml %.mli: %.mly
    $(OCAMLYACC) $*.mly
%.ml: %.mll
    $(OCAMLLEX) $*.mll
%.cmi: %.mli
    $(OCAMLC) $(OCAMLFLAGS) -c $*.ml
%.cmo: %.ml
    $(OCAMLC) $(OCAMLFLAGS) -c $*.ml

ML_DOMAIN_MAIN= syntax.ml \
        parser.ml \
        lexer.ml \
        calc.ml
CMO_DOMAIN_MAIN=$(ML_DOMAIN_MAIN:%.ml=%.cmo)

calc:   $(CMO_DOMAIN_MAIN)
        $(OCAMLC) -g -linkpkg -o $@ $+

clean:
    rm -rf calc *.o *.cm[oixa] *.annot *~ *.log *.output *.out *.mli parser.ml parser.mli
```

It returned an error:

```
menhir -v parser.mly
ocamlfind ocamlc -package ppx_deriving.std -package sedlex.ppx -package sedlex -package MenhirLib  -c parser.ml
File "parser.ml", line 1:
Error: Could not find the .cmi file for interface parser.mli.
make: *** [parser.cmo] Error 2
rm parser.ml
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in this rule:

```
%.cmi: %.mli
        $(OCAMLC) $(OCAMLFLAGS) -c $*.ml
```

The prerequisite is `.mli` but you pass `.ml` to the compiler.

Why don't you just use the [`$<` automatic variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#index-_0024_003c), then you don't have to worry about this?

```
%.ml %.mli: %.mly
        $(OCAMLYACC) $<
%.ml: %.mll
        $(OCAMLLEX) $<
%.cmi: %.mli
        $(OCAMLC) $(OCAMLFLAGS) -c $<
%.cmo: %.ml
        $(OCAMLC) $(OCAMLFLAGS) -c $<
```

Comment: I tired your solution, but it still returned the same error.

Comment: I don't know anything about `ocaml` compilers.  Looks like it can't find an included file (whatever that means in ocaml).  Maybe you have to add something like `-I.` to the compile line.

Comment: Also, you have a pattern rule that says how to build a `.cmi` file, but nothing in your makefile lists any `.cmi` files as a prerequisite of anything.  Based on the error you're seeing maybe the pattern `%.cmo : %.ml` should instead be `%.cmo: %.ml %.cmi` so that the `.cmi` file is built before the `.cmo` file?